# Jahmm's KmeansLearner

Tags: java, hidden-markov-models

I'm new with the Jahmm package, also I'm new with Java.

I'm having an error in KMeansLearner that says

```
Incompatible Types List<ObservationVector> cannot be converted to
                   List<? extends Observation Vector>
```

What does this mean? I have only observation vectors until now, and I declared it on headers. Can please anyone can tell how do I fix this? And if I want to use a `<ObservationReal>`, how does it affects the code?

Here is my code:

```
package jahmm;
import be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.*;
import be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.ForwardBackwardCalculator;
import be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.Hmm;
import be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.KMeansCalculator;
import be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.ObservationVector;
import be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.ObservationVector;
import be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.OpdfDiscrete;
import be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.OpdfMultiGaussian;
import be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.ViterbiCalculator;
import be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.draw.GenericHmmDrawerDot;
import be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.io.ObservationReader;
import be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.io.ObservationSequencesReader;
import be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.io.ObservationVectorReader;
import be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.learn.KMeansLearner;
import be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.learn.BaumWelchLearner;
import be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.learn.BaumWelchScaledLearner;
import be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.toolbox.MarkovGenerator;
import be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.ObservationReal;
import be.ac.ulg.montefiore.run.jahmm.OpdfInteger;

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;



/**
 *
 * @author
 */
public class Jahmm {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    //Instances instances;
    Reader reader;
    int i, j, k;

    try{
        //String filename = argv[0];
        String filex="dta_eat.seq";
        //filex = "Desktop\R\dt_junto.csv";
        String csvFileToRead = filex;
        reader = new FileReader(filex);

        List<ObservationVector> sequences =
                ObservationSequencesReader.readSequence(new ObservationVectorReader(), 
                        reader);

        reader.close();

        OpdfMultiGaussianFactory gMix = new OpdfMultiGaussianFactory(3);

        KMeansLearner<ObservationVector> kml;
        kml = new KMeansLearner<ObservationVector>(6,
                gMix, sequences);

        Hmm<ObservationVector> initHmm = kml.iterate();
        //Hmm<ObservationVector> fittedHmm = kml.learn();
        //Hmm<ObservationVector> initHmm = kml.iterate();



    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I'll really would appreciate your help.

Comment: The error is in the kml sentence, it marks it on "sequences"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get List of Lists:

```
Reader reader = new FileReader("vectors.seq");
List<List<ObservationVector>> v = ObservationSequencesReader.
  readSequences(new ObservationVectorReader(2), reader);
reader.close();
```

See this [example](http://www.run.montefiore.ulg.ac.be/~francois/software/jahmm/example/).

Comment: Thank you very much Jens. This helps me a lot, but tell me, what does the 2 means in "ObservationVectorReader(2)"? it means the states or the observations?

Comment: @BernardoOrtiz You find the [documentation](http://contexttoolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/apidoc/be/ac/ulg/montefiore/run/jahmm/io/ObservationVectorReader.html) on. The 2 is the Dimention `Constructs a reader of ObservationVector. Verifies the dimension of the observations read`